# Weak-* compact subset is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is it true that in a general normed vector space, a weak-* compact subset is bounded? I know if we assume the space is Banach, we can prove this by uniform boundedness principle, but what if the space is not Banach?

Answer (score 3):

Weak-* is a topology defined on the dual of a vector space, and the dual is always a Banach space.